# What's causing this odd behaviour with NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have been writing some unit tests. One object has a readonly property that returns an array that's populated by the file system. In order for the tests to not rely on the users filesystem I used swizzling in the tests to swap this property to one that will return a predefined array.

I noticed some weird behaviour though, some tests were failing which should have passed.

I tracked it down to `NSPredicate` and managed to isolate the behaviour in the code below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSArray *array;
@end

@implementation SomeObject
- (NSArray *)array {
    return @[];
}
@end

NSArray *array1(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];
}

NSArray *array2(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return @[@"d", @"e", @"f"];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        SomeObject *someObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"someObject.array: %@", someObject.array);
        NSPredicate *predicate;
        NSString *lookFor = @"a";

        //swap array for array1 function
        method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod([someObject class], @selector(array)), (IMP)array1);
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY array == %@", lookFor];
        NSLog(@"contains: %@ in %@: %@", lookFor, someObject.array, [someObject.array containsObject:lookFor] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        NSLog(@"NSPred: %@ in %@: %@", lookFor, someObject.array, [predicate evaluateWithObject:someObject] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

        //swap array for array2 function
        method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod([someObject class], @selector(array)), (IMP)array2);
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY array == %@", lookFor];
        NSLog(@"contains: %@ in %@: %@", lookFor, someObject.array, [someObject.array containsObject:lookFor] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        NSLog(@"NSPred: %@ in %@: %@", lookFor, someObject.array, [predicate evaluateWithObject:someObject] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }
}
```

it outputs

```
2014-09-05 18:05:10.169 Untitled[37520:507] someObject.array: (
)
2014-09-05 18:05:10.171 Untitled[37520:507] contains: a in (
    a,
    b,
    c
): YES
2014-09-05 18:05:10.171 Untitled[37520:507] NSPred: a in (
    a,
    b,
    c
): YES
2014-09-05 18:05:10.172 Untitled[37520:507] contains: a in (
    d,
    e,
    f
): NO
2014-09-05 18:05:10.172 Untitled[37520:507] NSPred: a in (
    d,
    e,
    f
): YES
```

Which is showing at the end that the predicate thinks `a` is contained in the array `[d, e, f]`.

What's going on here exactly and how can I change my tests to get this to behave as expected?

Comment: glossing over why you think swizzling for unit tests is a good idea... shouldnt that be `SELF.array`? typically for testing for inclusion in an array you would use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", myArray]` then call `evaluateWithObject:lookFor`

Comment: @BradAllred It's quite a useful tool in other languages but I'm quickly learning why it's not such a good idea in objective-C. Thank you, I think those are equivalent but looks like putting the predicate that way around side steps the KVC caching that jlehr pointed out. What would be a better way of changing the behaviour/implementation of an object in testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler test that may serve to shed more on the underlying issue:

```
// Assumes the SomeObject class and array1 and array2 IMPs are defined as
// shown in the example code in the OP's question.
//
- (void)testKVCAfterMethodSwizzle
{
    SomeObject *obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(obj.class, @selector(array));

    method_setImplementation(method, (IMP)array1);
    // NSLog(@"%@ %@", obj.array, [obj valueForKey:@"array"]);

    method_setImplementation(method, (IMP)array2);
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", obj.array, [obj valueForKey:@"array"]);
}
```

Try running this once, then uncomment the first `NSLog` statement and run it again. The initial log output should look something like this:

```
2014-09-05 15:51:22.814 xctest[67804:303] (
    d,
    e,
    f
) (
    d,
    e,
    f
)
```

However, once you uncomment the first `NSLog` statement, the output of the second log will look like this:

```
2014-09-05 15:58:38.989 xctest[67837:303] (
    d,
    e,
    f
) (
    a,
    b,
    c
)
```

Apparently, KVC (on which `NSPredicate`'s implementation depends) caches method IMPs itself to reduce the overhead of subsequent calls. This may be one of the reasons that Apple seems to discourage the use of swizzling in production code. If you must swizzle methods, the best time to so would likely be during or immediately after class loading.

**Edit**

One possible workaround for this problem would be to define a more general implementation of the swizzled method. For example, you could write a swizzled implementation that simply returns the value of a global variable, for example:

```
static NSArray *ArrayToReturn;

NSArray *selectedArray(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return ArrayToReturn;
}
```

Your test case class could override `+load` to apply the swizzle:

```
+ (void)load
{
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([SomeObject class], @selector(array));
    method_setImplementation(method, (IMP)selectedArray);
}
```

Then your test methods might look something like this:

```
- (void)testSwizzleWithSelectedArray1
{
    ArrayToReturn = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];

    SomeObject *obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(obj.array, [obj valueForKey:@"array"]);
}

- (void)testSwizzleWithSelectedArray2
{
    ArrayToReturn = @[@"d", @"e", @"f"];

    SomeObject *obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(obj.array, [obj valueForKey:@"array"]);
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks @jlehr I should have tried harder to produce a simpler example :) It looks like I'm only going to run into issues trying to use swizzling in my tests. What alternatives are there?

Comment: @GP89 Your welcome, it's an interesting question. Please see my edit for a potential workaround.